# How do I check a text field value against words in an array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My array has string values:

```
var bannedWords = ["cat","dog","test"]
```

My text input field checks if the value contains words from the array:

```
var title = $j('#edit-content').val()
if ($j.inArray(title, bannedWords) != -1) { alert("it's inside the array") }
```

When the value is "cat", it works as expected.  When the value is "the cat is black", I  want the alert because "cat" is inside the input value.

I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't know how can I do this?
with some kind of loop in the value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On a side note, fix the use of single quotes in your alert. `alert('it's inside the array')` should be `alert("it's inside the array")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) out of your array and use it to test the input:

```
// The 'i' flag matches values regardless of case.
var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + bannedWords.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');

// Regex would equal /\bcat\b|\bdog\b|\btest\b/i
var valid = !regex.test($("#edit-content").val());
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/aZbWP/1

Comment: in order to block CAT (uppercase) as well, what would the regex be?

Comment: You could just pass `i` to the `RegExp` constructor. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, is there a way to do the same thing but for words with diacritics too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to split the value into an array an test each word individually:

```
var words = $j('#edit-content').val().split(' ');
$.each(words, function(index, word) {
    if ($j.inArray(word, bannedWords) != -1) { 
        alert('it\'s inside the array') 
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/GdjBq/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to check:

```
function in_string(words, string) {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (string.indexOf(words[i]) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var valid = in_string(bannedWords, $j('#edit-content').val())
```

Although I would suggest that you do this serverside. It's not hard to submit the request manually and bypass your JS validation.

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) in your bannedWords array would be more powerful (you can for example check for 'cat', 'Cat' and 'CAT' all in one go) and enable you to do what you want more concisely.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/PS9FG/1

You'd need to adapt this code slightly to fit your own (e.g., the line of jQuery you have).

```
var bannedWords = [
  /cat/i,    // the i after each expression means case-insensitive
  /dog/i,
  /test/i
];


document.getElementById('checkBtn').onclick = function() {
    var bWrd = bannedWords.length;
    while (bWrd) {    // loop through each pattern in the array
        bWrd -= 1;
        if (document.getElementById('edit-content').value.match(bannedWords[bWrd])) {
            alert("it's inside the array");
        }
    }
};
```

But hopefully that gives you an idea of how it could work.