# how to avoid abusive input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm just learning jQuery and want to make a form. when anyone  insert a abusive word/words  the submit button won't be enabled and also the entered input  will be  cleared. Please help me if anyone can do this. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
$("#txt").keyup(function(){ if ($(this).val()) {
$("#btn").removeAttr('disabled');
alert("please enter some valid input");
}
else{$("#btn").attr('disabled','disabled'); }
});
});
 </script>  

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt" />

<input type="submit" id="btn" disabled />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "sensible input" ?

Comment: Just making sure - "sensible" is usually a good thing.

Comment: what do you mean by "sensible input, explain more about it

Comment: i mean to say if anyone type some abusive words then the submit  button won't be enabled. i'm not good in english, and i'm really sorry for that. please give a positive vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of words to filter all the abusive words. Then use a [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242898/6373708) to test your input if it's valid or not.

Here is my try:

```js
var arr = [ "bad", "ugly" ],
  regex = new RegExp('\\b' + arr.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');


$(function() {

  $("#txt").keyup(function() {

  if(!regex.test(this.value)){ 
      $("#btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
     alert("You enter a bad word!");
      $("#btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    
    if( !$("#txt").val()){
      $("#btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
    
  });
  
   $("#clear").on("click", function() {
            $("#txt").val("");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />

<input type="submit" id="btn" disabled />
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @c.k . This is what i'm exactly looking for.